# Message + add class

Tags: 7, theming

i need to add another class to message div. That class must be the name of the module that creates the message.

Example: A new mail is added via "Simple suscription" module. Then the message div should be "div.error.simple_suscription"

I need this since i have, contact/comment form within #main, and the #footer has a form for newsletter suscrptions. Plus i'm making images for the messages.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as described [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7#comment-23023) you can add your classes to message div:

```
drupal_set_message(t('Something horrible just happened.'),'error simple_suscription');
```

Comment: Thanks sheena_d and Mohammad Ali Akbari. I just added the class to my "simple suscription" module. That's all! many thanks.

Comment: I tried using the above code but its not outputting the custom class

Answer (score 2):

The theme function that handles the HTML output for system messages is [theme_status_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7)

Unfortunately, the API function that modules use to set status messages, [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7), does not collect any information about where the messages originate. Thus, there is no way to add module-specific classes to a system message when it is themed. The only option is to add the class when the message is created via the $type variable in drupal_set_message().

I do not see any reasonable solution if you are hoping to use this technique for all messages on a site and/or messages from core or contrib modules.