# Drupal set message class

Tags: 7

I've been trying to add a class to a drupal_set_message() function. i found [one article](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29778/message-add-class) that said it worked, but i could not get it to work on mine. am i missing something?

I have `drupal_set_message(t('an error has occured'),'custom-error');`

these are the only output i get from the html

```
<div class="alert alert-block">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
an error has occured</div>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the article plz? It seems fine.

Comment: you are missing the $type parameter  status , warning or error. the second parameter is message type separated by space your class name

Comment: refer this link https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7#comment-23023

Answer (score 2):

For drupal set message below is a syntax.

```
drupal_set_message($message = NULL, $type = 'status', $repeat = TRUE);
```

**Parameters**

**string $message:** (optional) The translated message to be displayed to the user. For consistency with other messages, it should begin with a capital letter and end with a period.

**string $type:** (optional) The message's type. Defaults to 'status'. These values are supported:

'**status**'

'**warning**'

'**error**'

You should pass any one of the status message with your custom class separated with space as shown below

```
drupal_set_message(t('an error has occured'),' status custom-error');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I'm gonna go and try if this will work. I'll get back to you shortly

Comment: hello. I did it as follows

drupal_set_message(t('an error has occured'),' status custom-alert');

but it is still not rendering the class. should i create a custom theme_status_message() instead?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, i created a theme_status_message on my template.php, inside  it contains the default theme_status_message with some minor changes. Cleared the cache and the classes are adding. It's weird how it's not working when I didn't create one even though it was in the theme.inc file.

Also, it seems like the default has become 'status' instead of 'success' before the changes. Anyone know how to chnage the default without changing the bootstrap.inc file?